# Round brackets for latex(Matrix(…))

Tags: sympy

By default, `latex(Matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])` gives a matrix surrounded by square brackets. How can I use round brackets instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
latex(Matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), mat_delim='(', mat_str='matrix')
```